# Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Line aparently gets clipped when using tiny scale in RenderTransform

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Winrt with Windows 8.1

I am using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Ellipse to render planets and moons in our solar system in 2d. I define ellipse objects with the correct position and size of the planets and then I create a common RenderTransform which scales the large values of position and size down to pixels on a canvas. The transform is also used to rotate and translate the entire view.
Viewing the entire system as a whole would make the scale such that all the planets would be less than one pixel, so I scale the planets to never be less than 5 pixels on screen.

This works fine, and was to give the basic background of my problem.

I now want to render the orbits as well as other paths through this system and I thought I would use a Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Line for this, since the Shapes.Line apparently does not have a render transform which I need.

When, as an example, I define a line from 0,0 (the sun) to 150E+9,0 (orbit distance of Earth  in meters) using a StrokeThickness of 1E+9 (approx one Sun radius in meters), I expect to see a line from the sun to the orbit radius of earth with a thickness of half the sun.

What I see is nothing (image 1).

When I then zoom in, by changing the common renderTransform of all objects, at one point when the scale is approx 1/1276062 the line does become visible (image 2) and it does look correct. It is a big line starting at the center of the sun (which at this zoom level takes up most of the screen). 
If I then zoom in even further to approx 1/2948, the line again becomes invisible.

At all zoom levels, the ellipses I am using for the sun and planets, behave as expected.

It seems to be an issue of premature clipping by the render engine. It mistakenly think the line is too thin to be seen and then clips it, but that is just a guess and I have not been able to get any different results from mocking about with verious clip, width and height settings on the line. Might note that I am new on winrt.

[image: Invisible line though it should be visible at this magnification]
[image: Visible line though it is only slightly more zoomed in than before]

Comment: The reason this works with ellipsis in my case is apparently that I am using a TransformGroup: one transform scaling the ellipses up from a diameter of 1 to very large (diameter of planet) and then the other transform scales it back down again to screen size.
This apparently works fine.
If I on the other hand create an object (ellipses or line) with initial huge size and then scale that down to screen size using a single transform, then it doesn't work, so...
Ordinary size object transformed up and then transformed down in size works.
Huge size object transformed down in size doesn't.

Comment: The two things I would try checking are: [UseLayoutRounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.uselayoutrounding) and [CompositeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.compositemode). Both may have an effect when you get to the nitty-gritty of pixel zooming, especially LayoutRounding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking an interest in this issue. Neither one did seem to make a difference though.
I have now resorted to doing this "by hand" instead. I still keep a transform matrix to convert from real (large) values to screen coordinates, but now I read it myself and position and scale the graphics rather than using two transforms and relying on the system doing the work.